# Quick sort with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, quicksort

I need to code a quick sort algorithm in C as homework. This is the prototype I was given:

```
static inline
int* choose_pivot(int *left, int *right) {
    /* FIX ME */
}

/*
 * partition(left, right, pivot): push value less than *pivot on the left
 * return the new pivot.
 */
 int* partition(int *left, int *right, int *pivot) {
     /* FIX ME */
 } 

 /*
 * quick_sort(left, right)
 */
 void quick_sort(int *left, int *right) {
     /* FIX ME */
 }
```

where `left` is the pointer to the first element of the array and `right`, the pointer to the last element (excluded). I wrote the following code:

```
static inline
int* choose_pivot(int *left, int *right) {
    return &left[(right - left)/2];
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}  

int* partition(int *left, int *right, int *pivot) {
    int *i, *q;
    q = right;
    i = left ;
    while ( q > pivot ) {
        while ( pivot < i )
            pivot++;
        while ( q > i )
            q--;
        if ( *q > *pivot ) {
           swap(pivot,q);
        }
    }
    swap(left, q);
    return q ;
}

void quick_sort(int *left, int *right) {
    if(left >= right)
        return;

    int *pivot = partition(left, right, choose_pivot(left, right));
    quick_sort(left, pivot-1);
    quick_sort(pivot + 1, right);
}
```

I am running 3 kind of tests: one on a sorted array, one on a reverse sorted one and,
one on reverse sorted one. the first test works well, but the second and this ones fails. Basically meaning the functions doesn't work. I can't find any documentation on what I am supposed to do since all quick sort algorithm uses its length instead of a pointer on the last element and I couldn't adapt the ones I've found to my representation. What is going wrong here?

EDIT:

My new partition function now looks like this after the comments:

```
int* partition(int *left, int *right, int *pivot) {
    int *i, *q;
    q = right;
    i = left ;
    int p = *pivot;

    while ( q > pivot ) {
        while ( p < *i )
            pivot++;
        while ( *q > *i )
            q--;
        if ( q > pivot ) {
            swap(pivot,q);
        }
    }

    swap(left, q);
    return q ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing the pivot?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to adapt the code [here](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/quick-sort-2852.aspx).

Comment: Normally, you would use the leftmost element as the pivot.  If you choose to use the middle element as the pivot (to handle presorted lists better), you would swap it with the leftmost element before partitioning.  It seems like you learned this at some point because I see `swap(left, q);` at the end of the partitioning function, which only makes sense if the pivot were the leftmost element.  Edit: in the code you linked to, the pivot is the leftmost element (`i = a[lower]`).

Comment: After taking another look, your partition function has quite a few problems.  You are comparing pointers instead of comparing values: `pivot < i` should be `*pivot < *i`.  But better yet you should keep the pivot value in a variable, `int pivotVal = *pivot;`.

Comment: @JS1 Where should I compare the values instead of the pointers?

Comment: In the code you linked to, there are 4 comparisons in the partition function: `while ( q >= p )` is an index comparison (pointer in your code),  `while ( a[p] < i )` is a value comparison, `while ( a[q] > i )` is a value comparison, `if ( q > p )` is an index comparison (pointer).

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your approach:

- `pivot` points to an element in the array which might change during the course of the `partition` function. You should swap the value pointed to by `pivot` with that of the first element and set `pivot = left` to to prevent this problem.
- you compare the pointers instead of the values in the loops in function `partition`... instead of `while (pivot < i)` you should write `while (*pivot < *i)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple function of quick sort using pointers..

```
quicksort( void *a, int low, int high )
  {
  int pivot;
  /* Termination condition! */
  if ( high > low )
    {
    pivot = partition( a, low, high );
    quicksort( a, low, pivot-1 );
    quicksort( a, pivot+1, high );
    }
  }
```

Function of Partition

```
int partition( void *a, int low, int high )
  {
  int left, right;
  void *pivot_item;
  pivot_item = a[low];
  pivot = left = low;
  right = high;
  while ( left < right ) {
    /* Move left while item < pivot */
    while( a[left] <= pivot_item ) left++;
    /* Move right while item > pivot */
    while( a[right] > pivot_item ) right--;
    if ( left < right ) SWAP(a,left,right);
    }
  /* right is final position for the pivot */
  a[low] = a[right];
  a[right] = pivot_item;
  return right;
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not how I'm supposed to do it. The quick sort function must take a pointer to the first element and the last element (excluded) of the array.It is explicitly written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
void quick_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int p = a[n / 2];
    int *l = a;
    int *r = a + n - 1;
    while (l <= r) {
        if (*l < p) {
            l++;
        }
        else if (*r > p) {
            r--;
        }
        else {
            int t = *l;
            *l = *r;
            *r = t;
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    quick_sort(a, r - a + 1);
    quick_sort(l, a + n - l);
}

int main () {
    int a[] = {4, 65, 2, -31, 0, 99, 2, 83, 782, 1};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    quick_sort(a, n);
    printf("%d", a[]);
    return 0;
}


//  [1]: https://www.cse.ust.hk/~dekai/271/notes/L01a/quickSort.pdf
//  [2]: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/quicksort.html
 // [3]: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort
```

Comment: Your function potentially works but it does not address the OP's issue.